# Automatically Change Class name and id data within class

Tags: php, recursion

My goal is to create a PHP script where the inputted Item name recursively changes. This will change the first number to the starting number I enter and then add 1 for the class name and the id. I can't wrap my head around this. It's simply to make my life easier. Trying to see if PHP can do what I want, or if anyone has an example in another language I'd be happy to look into that too. Here's what I mean:

I enter the following in a textarea:

```
    class Item0
    {
        side="EMPTY";
        vehicle="Item_acc_pointer_IR";
        id=1;
        position[]={3276.23,8.757,12908.7};
        azimut=278.764;
        offsetY=16.1706;
    };
    class Item1
    {
        side="EMPTY";
        vehicle="Item_muzzle_snds_L";
        id=2;
        position[]={3276.33,8.757,12908.6};
        azimut=0;
        offsetY=16.1784;
    };
    ...
```

I want the smallest Item to be changed to the number I enter for both the Item class and the id= data. Let's say 500 for Item and 323 for id=. This then is outputted in another textarea. I can handle the textarea's and the formatting. I just need to know how to make PHP look for these specific items.

```
    class Item500
    {
        side="EMPTY";
        vehicle="Item_acc_pointer_IR";
        id=323;
        position[]={3276.23,8.757,12908.7};
        azimut=278.764;
        offsetY=16.1706;
    };
    class Item501
    {
        side="EMPTY";
        vehicle="Item_muzzle_snds_L";
        id=324;
        position[]={3276.33,8.757,12908.6};
        azimut=0;
        offsetY=16.1784;
    };
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Scott

Comment: What you are asking is totally unclear (I read it twice). So unclear I'm not able to say why is it so unclear. Crazy!

Comment: I think you're pissing the point of classes.... surely these are all the same class, simply different instances

Comment: These are NOT PHP classes. These are classes for a game server. I just have to change each class name from Item0, Item1, Item2, etc.. and I wanted to integrate a quick way to get this done for me into an existing PHP application. The following should happen:

`class Item0` should change to `class Item500`. `class Item1` should change to `class501`. `class Item2` should change to `class Item502` and so on. Basically allowing me to copy and paste from the outputted list of classes which is otherwise exactly like the original. The id will do the same. Both will have different starting numbers.

Comment: The classes I am giving you are an export from a 3D editing engine in ArmA 3. The classes aren't something I can stop from using. It's part of the game that goes in the mission.sqm file. So, I just need to know how to recursively change numbers.

Comment: PHP doesn't provide any mechanism for automagically creating hundreds of identical classes, because that's contrary to the very principles of OOP. It does provide you with mechanisms to create a single class, and create different instances of that class with different properties. And your comments about the 3D editing engine still don't explain why you need to create 500 identical class definitions.

Comment: If you absolutely need to do something like this, consider PHP7's anonymous classes